# Quadratic Sieve improvement idea

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, sieve-theory

I got an idea for Quadratic Sieve improvement, but I don't know if someone already tried it or how efficient it is. Please tell me if it can work.

Let $N$ be the number we wish to factor.

We can look at the congruence of squares $x^2 \equiv y^2\pmod{N^2}$, if we can find such $x,y$ we can compute the gcd of $x+y$ and $N$ to find a nontrivial factor of $N$(if it's trivial we just need to find more $x,y$ pairs)

$y$ can be stated as $x^2-N^2 = y^2$ -> $(x-N)(x+N) = y^2$

We can then find a pair of $a,c$ such that $x+N=ac$ and $a,c \approx \sqrt{N}$, let's call the $x$ that satisfy this $x`$, then for each $x$ in $f(i)=ia+x`$ we can write $y$ as $(ia + x`-N)(x`+ia +N) = y^2$ -> $a(ia + x`-N)(c+i) = y^2$

Finally, we can start searching for $x,y$ pairs that satisfy $x^2 \equiv y^2\pmod{N^2}$ in

$$f(i)=a(ia + x`-N)(c+i)$$

When $f(i)$ is a square then $gcd(\sqrt{f(i)} + ia+x`,N)$ has a high chance if being a non trivial divisor of $N$

If we start running on $f(i)$ from $i\approx \frac{N-x}{a}$ then $ia+x`-N\approx{\sqrt{N}}$ and also $c+i\approx{\sqrt{N}}$. We can use the same technics as we use in QS . Leveregix Dixon's factorization method together with sieving and loggaritmic approximation for faster sieve.

The only difference is that we are building two squares instead of one, we are looking for $(ia + x`-N)$ to be a square and also $(c+i)$ to be a square, as they cannot have any commonly dividing values, except $2$ and the factors of $N$.

Proof:

If a prime $p$ divides $(x-N)$, $(x+N)$ then it must divides $(x-N + 2N)$ since it equals to $(x+N)$. And so it must divide $2N$, that can only happen if $p=2$ or $p$ is a factor of $N$

My theory is that the sieving should be much easier since we are not dealing with squares like in the classing QS where we are searching for $f(x)=x^2-N$ to be a square or SIQS where we are searching for $f(x)=a(ax^2-bx+c)$ to be a square. However from the other side, we need to make two numbers to be a square, so I am not so sure it's indeed easier and hence asking the question here.

Comment: The "classical" quadratic sieve does not search for $x^2-N=y^2$ , but for a nontrivial congruence $x^2\equiv y^2\mod N$. A Refinement is the multipolynomial quadratic sieve. Numbers of special forms can be factored faster (but I never understood how this acceleration works). So I am not sure whether your method is something new.

Comment: @Peter actually it does during the sieving stage, but you are right about the congruence of squares, it's used at the matrix part of the algorithm, it's a core concept taken from the Dixon factorization method. With my idea, I think the sieving part will be faster. Because all of the primes are in the prime base, it's cheaper switching polynomials and the growth speed is linear, unlike in QS where it's quadratic.

Comment: I am not an expert in how the modern quadratic sieve versions work exactly , but I guess many improvements have been done since the main idea based on Dixon.