# Can each odd composite integer be represented as $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$

Tags: factoring

Each odd composite integer can be represented as $a^2-b^2$, it's the basics for Fermat's factorization method.

I got an idea of exploring an integer factorization algorithm(see my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811843/quadratic-sieve-improvement-idea)) that is based on the assumption that each odd composite integer can be represented as $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

Can you prove this assumption, or show where it fails?

Comment: Sure; if $n$ is odd, so is $N=n^2$. Represent $N$ as desired and then you're done.

Comment: Any integer $n$ can be represented as $\sqrt{n^2-0^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is equivalent to solving $n^2=a^2-b^2.$

But if $n$ is odd then so is $n^2.$ So your original result applies to $n^2.$

---

(You don’t need $n$ composite for your first result, just $n$ odd.  If $n=2k-1$ then $k^2-(k-1)^2=2k-1=n.$)